# Consistency results using nonstandard models

Tags: lo.logic, set-theory, forcing

Are there any consistency results in set theory (or  in mathematics) that can be proved using nonstandard models of ZFC but not using transitive models of ZFC?

Comment: The obvious one that "Not all models of ZFC agree on the natural numbers", I guess is too obvious? As would Con(ZFC) sort of statements, I suppose. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. Harvey Friedman has identified several (natural) combinatorial statements that are equivalent to the $1$-consistency of $\mathsf{ZFC}$ or strengthenings of it via large cardinals (here, $1$-$\mathrm{Con}(T)$ is the assertion that all $\Sigma^0_1$ consequences of $T$ are true). In particular, this means that the statements in question hold in the standard model, and any model of their negation is necessarily non-standard (in fact, it is not an $\omega$-model).

See for example

> Harvey M. Friedman. *Finite functions and the necessary use of large cardinals*, Ann. of Math. (2), **148 (3)**, (1998), 803–893. [MR1670057 (2002b:03108)](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1670057).

Harvey's research has actually produced a nice variety of such statements.

If one relaxes your requirements that these be *consistency* results, and that any proof must *necessarily* involve non-standard models, a different example appears in the work of Greg Hjorth on descriptive set theory of equivalence relations, see

> Greg Hjorth. *Thin equivalence relations and effective decompositions*, J. Symbolic Logic, **58 (4)**, (1993), 1153–1164. [MR1253912 (95c:03119)](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1253912).

In his argument, Greg must analyze non-standard Ehrenfeucht-Mostowski models (coming from sharps). There is actually a different version of the argument, due to Sy Friedman and Boban Velickovic. Their argument also uses non-standard models, but their methods are different. I do not know, however, that this use is essential.